# Android Studio : Client not ready yet... Timed out waiting for process to appear on device

Tags: android-emulator, adb, android-studio-3.0

Trying to run my app but it keeps showing the following error. I have tried every available solution on stackoverflow.com but the problem still remain.
I have attached manifest file for reference. Android Studio3.2.1 target SDK-28

12/27 01:36:23: Launching app
$ adb push F:\Android_projects\CaliberGaming\CaliberGaming\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk /data/local/tmp/com.caliber.mskhan.calibergaming
$ adb shell pm install -t -r "/data/local/tmp/com.caliber.mskhan.calibergaming"
Success
APK installed in 3 s 482 ms
Client not ready yet..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.caliber.mskhan.calibergaming">

    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
    -->

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

    <application
        android:name=".helper.MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_descriptor"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">

        <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
        -->
        <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
            android:required="false" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="preloaded_fonts"
            android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.razorpay.ApiKey"
            android:value="rzp_test_PpOinqLyVBHOcP" />

        <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".RegistrationActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Login" />
        <activity
            android:name=".HomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_home"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ProfilePage"
            android:parentActivityName=".HomeActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".CenterActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".GamersProfile"
            android:parentActivityName=".HomeActivity"
            tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute" />
        <activity
            android:name=".CenterRequestActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_center_request" />
        <activity
            android:name=".FollowList"
            android:label="Following" />

        <service
            android:name=".TimingService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" />

        <activity
            android:name=".EventInfoActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_event_info"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".TeamProfile"
            android:parentActivityName=".HomeActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute" />
        <activity
            android:name=".PendingActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".HomeActivity"
            tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute" />
        <activity
            android:name=".EventsActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".HomeActivity"
            tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute" />
        <activity
            android:name=".LeaderBoards"
            android:parentActivityName=".HomeActivity"
            tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute" />
        <activity android:name=".ChangePassword" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ForgotPassword"
            android:parentActivityName=".Login"
            tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MatchesDOTA"
            android:parentActivityName=".TeamProfile"
            tools:targetApi="jelly_bean" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MatchesCSGO"
            android:parentActivityName=".TeamProfile"
            tools:targetApi="jelly_bean" />
        <activity
            android:name=".VerificationActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".Login"
            tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute" />
        <activity android:name="com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".GettingLocation" />

        <activity android:name=".SteamLogin"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />

        <activity android:name=".PaymentResult" />

        <activity android:name=".products" />

        <receiver
            android:name=".receiver.ConnectivityReceiver"
            android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                    android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"
                    tools:ignore="BatteryLife" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name=".service.LocationService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" />

        <service
            android:name=".service.GPSTracker"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```